# Oracle trace all SELECTS

Tags: oracle

I need to do a task but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is the problem:

I have about 1000 tables on a Oracle Database and many processes.

Each process does one or more SELECT on one or many tables.
Because it's almost impossible to look in the source code to find which process does which SELECT on which tables, I would like to have some kind of trigger on SELECT on every table.
The idea is that I will launch the processes one by one to be able to see which tables will query.

I know that there is no trigger on SELECT, but is there anything else?

I need to do this in a one shot, just to recover the necessary info, it will not run every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could activate [auditing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm#i2059073). You can audit all SELECT with:

```
AUDIT SELECT TABLE;
```

You can specify `BY SESSION` so that only one record will be written to the audit trail per table accessed per session.

Your [`AUDIT_TRAIL`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams016.htm#i1125027) parameter must be set to either `DB` or `OS`. If it is set to `DB`, the audit trail will be written to the `SYS.AUD$` table.

Comment: Yes, this might be the best solution to my problem. I just have to talk to the DBA to activate the AUDIT_TRAIL because for the moment it's disactivated. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Note that on *nix system, OS logging goes to the directory of your choice. On windows, it goes to the event log.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can map a "process" in your terminology to a particular Oracle session, you could [trace the Oracle session](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace).  That would show you all the SQL statements executed by that session.

You could also potentially do a S[QL*Net trace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aNet_FAQ#I_have_some_trouble_with_SQL.2ANet._How_does_one_produce_a_trace_file.3F) from whatever the client machine is (note that the "client machine" in a three-tier environment is the application server).  A SQL*Net trace tends not to be nearly as easy to work with, however.

Comment: This solution is not the best, because I will have alot alot of log. Each process does many selects, so it will be almost impossible to retrieve the necessary info from the log file (the huge log files)

Comment: @CC - I'm not sure I follow the objection.  If you want to see the literal SQL (and potentially the bind variables) for each request, it would seem that you need and want quite a bit of logging.  If you only care about a subset of the SQL, there are much easier approaches but that's not what you asked for initially).

Comment: Ah, non. I want only the table names, for each process.

Comment: @CC - Ah, OK.  Then Vincent's suggestion to enable auditing is probably what you want.